# LED driver 3.5V 25A. Low voltage, high current

Tags: led, buck-boost

I need to make a driver for an LED that works at 3.5 V 25 A. My idea was to make a DC/DC regulator from 12 V to 3.5 V and then a current limiter, but I'm at a loss as to which IC to use or how to build a driver.

The LED is the CFT - 90 W model from Luminus.

Comment: Welcome to [electronics.se]! However, recommendations for a specific product are off-topic so we can't just tell you which IC to use. You are welcome to ask for help to build a driver for it, but you need to show what you've got so far and explain your requirements.

Comment: Is this mains powered or DC powered? LED datasheet? What dimming range do you want?

Comment: No point in following a voltage output with a current limiter, just make a constant current output.

Comment: An LED has a range of voltage (only a graph of typical voltage is shown on the datasheet) therefore a regulated current is used instead. How will you cool that extremely bright and powerful LED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 feedback requirements for safe operation.

1. Junction Over-Temp Protection (OTP) using the heatsink and
2. Over-Current Protection (OCP)  where 1) has priority over 2)

There are also stringent requirements for cooling, not much different than a forced air CPU cooler for a 150W CPU.

The general rule of thumb is to measure what you wish to control.  For current a 50 mV current sensor could be used but would be 2 W resistor with R = 50mV/22.5 A = 2.22 mohm or a folded copper strip.  The board has a Murata Thermistor which can also be conditioned for accurate heatsink thermal sensing.

The method of step-down voltage conversions are many such as those used on motherboards from a regulated 5V supply but instead of sensing output voltage, you would feedback and compare the sensed current with the ramped up control voltage to reduce the stress and improve stability.

What you choose depends on your budget, design skills, search results and learning skills.

[image]

The goal should be **not to exceed Tj = 90 'C.** using OTP and OCP.

For the DIY design, consider a CPU cooler and 5V rail from an old PC PSU > 250W for an old MOBO.  That part would be free.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a mains powered [4.2V 30A](https://www.meanwell.fr/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/HSP-150/HSP-150-spec.pdf) switching power supply (perhaps even a [5V](https://www.meanwell.fr/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/RSP-150/RSP-150-spec.pdf) one) and hack the feedback to make output voltage controllable. This would avoid having to design a high current buck.

Instead of measuring LED current, I'd just measure light output and base the feedback on that, with a temperature sensor to turn it off if it overheats.

Comment: 1. Have you done this? (how many times?)  2. What do you think of Tony's suggestion to use an old PC PSU? The power wasted as heat in the current-sensing element always bothered me, but I couldn't argue that current-controlled was better. Are there any complications / pathologies with doing it this way, of which you are aware?  Thanks.

Comment: No, I didn't try it. If you use a PC PSU, you'd have to check how much current it can actually output on the 5V rail.

Comment: This [4+ gold star rated $67 PSU from Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Apevia-ATX-PR800W-Prestige-Certified-Compliance/dp/B07NWZZXHQ) puts out 20A at 3.3V which is very close to his desired 25A at 3.5V, and may work out great.  The 800W PSU also puts out 5V @ 20A, and 12V @ 66A, and is also 80+ Gold Certified, which I believe delivers 90+ % efficiency. Hacking the 5V rail for this PSU might do it, as the 5V x 20A = 100W would likely deliver his 3.5V x 25A = 87.5W most likely without problem if hacked as you suggested.

Comment: Yes this would probably work

Answer (score 2):

General technique: step-down DCDC and regulate on current with a sense element.

25A with a sense resistor is possible, but requires kind of a low sense value which could be tricky to design, requiring accurate calibration and low-offset amplifiers. Analog Devices / Linear Tech makes some excellent current-sense op-amps for this.

Perhaps using a Hall sensor would work.